# topology question on uncountable ordered sets, showing that $\mathbb L$ has a least element.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\omega$ be an uncountable ordered set, every initial segment of which is
countable (if such exists). Give, $[0,1)$ $\subset\mathbb{R}$ the standard order. Give, $\mathbb{L} = \omega X [0,1)$ the dictionary order.
Show that $\mathbb{L}$ has a least element. Is $\mathbb{L}$ topologically equivalent to $[0,\infty)$ $\subset \mathbb{R}$ (with the standard topology)?

Need help on this, I tried doing it using contradiction but its not working. Can someone suggest me a direct proof for this?

Also, I am unclear as to what its asking me to do for the 2nd part.

Answer (score 0):

No, the first part is quite false. $"\omega"=\Bbb Q + \omega_1$ (as an ordered sum, so all elements of the copy of the rationals (or we could take $\Bbb Z$ instead if you like it better) lie before the copy of $\omega_1$ (the [first uncountable ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal)), which does exist. So demanding initial segments to be countable does not imply a minumum exists.

But maybe your text refers to the well-ordered set with all initial segments countable (normal notation, as said, $\omega_1$, but $\Omega$ is used in Munkres) and in that case $\Omega \times [0,1)$ ordered lexicographically has a least element $(0,0)$, but is *not* topologically (nor order-theoretically) equivalent to $[0,\infty)$ as the latter is separable and the former is not, for starters. Also $\Bbb L$ is non-metrisable and countably compact, while $[0,\infty)$ is metrisable and not countably compact, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response, bt I dont know how to show that L has a least element? Also, can you explain more on why its not topologically equivalent?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun that $L$ has a minimum is because the well-ordered $\Omega$ has a minimum, namely $0$. So $(0,0)$ is $\min(\Bbb L)$ then follows. See Munkes’ text for proofs of my assertions.

Comment: Oh, I didnt know this has been proved in Munkres, can you please tell me which page number or chapter is it?

Comment: hey, I am sorry to disturb you but in my notes also, its the same Ω   mentioned that u were talking about. But, how do I declare a subbasis for this since it tells me to give a standard order and then dictionary order on that. Can you please re-post your answer showing how $\mathbb{L}$ is the least element?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun $\Omega$ is a well-ordered uncountable set by construction, such that for all $\alpha \in \Omega$, the set $\{x \in \Omega: x < \alpha\}=(-\infty,\alpha)$ is countable; it starts with $0,1,2,3,,$ as all ordinals, so $0$ is its minimum. The subbase is just the standard ordered subbase of open rays. $\Bbb L=\Omega \times [0,1)$ ordered lexicographically. So trivially $(0,0)$ is the minimum.